# Using fgets() to recieve a sentence input

Tags: c, string, input

I seem to be having an issue with some code. The purpose of the code is to take a phrase and convert it to pig latin.

It seems that this code will not take user input, at the block where we say if (x == 1). What it will do is it will automatically take NULL as input to fgets, and I'm clueless as to why.

I've spent entirely too much time on this problem, and I would appreciate any advice on how to improve this code. Please leave a comment on how I can improve my questions in the future.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int pigLatin()
{
    char phrase[250] = { 0 };
    char pigPhrase[300] = { 0 };
    char * tokens[300] = { 0 };
    char fileName[260] = { 0 };

    FILE * read = NULL;
    FILE * write = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    int x;
    int size;

    while (i < 10000) {
        i++;
        x = 0;
        printf("Enter one(1) to input via console, two(2) to input via .txt, or (3) to exit:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        if (x == 1) {
            printf_s("Enter your Phrase Do not include:\nany punctuation, words less than 2 letters long, or words seperated by blanks:");

            fgets(phrase, sizeof phrase, stdin);

            phrase[strlen(phrase) - 1] = '\0';

            printf_s("\nPhrase Entered:%s\n", phrase);
            system("pause");
        }
        else if (x == 2)
        {
            printf("Enter name of input file:\n");
            scanf_s("%s", fileName, 260);
            printf("File name:\n%s\n", fileName);
            if (fopen_s(&write, fileName, "r") == 0)
            {
                scanf_s("%s", phrase, 260);

            }
        }
        else if (x == 3)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Statement\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use fgets in c++ at all?

Comment: @DYZ I think its obvious that it is C wrongly tagged as C++.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys my bad.

Comment: @Urist_mcDwarf - the most important aspect of taking user input is **checking the return** of whatever function was used to determine success or failure. Then you further check any range values (if required) and finally account for any characters left in the input buffer (see Swordfish answer below). What gets left in the input buffer by `scanf` is the main reason new C programmers have problems with `scanf` and one of the main reasons `fgets` is recommended for all user input.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &number);` will read an integer but leave everything else in the stream including the `'\n'` generated by pressing [Enter] after entering the number. This newline left in the stream is then consumed by `fgets()` without giving you a chance for input.

Clear the stream after using `scanf()`:

```
int clear(FILE *stream)
{
    int ch;  // reads until EOF or a newline is encountered:
    while((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

// ...
int number;
if(scanf("%d", &number) != 1) {
    // handle error;
}

clear(stdin);

char foo[42];
fgets(foo, sizeof(foo), stdin);

// ...
```

Comment: What exactly is a stream? I know it has something to do with files, and i know that stdin is a type of stream. also EOF is a key word of sorts correct? Also what kind of error are you expecting to see from my program with that if statement?